# Object returning itself in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Let's say I have an object that has a method that returns the object itself.

```
var mystate = {
    init: function() {
        return this;
    },
    run: function() {
        console.log("!");
    }
}
```

Then I run this code:

```
var status = mystate.init();
mystate.run();
status.run();
```

In Firefox this does print two "!" signs in the console, but somehow in Chrome it prints the first one but I get an error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'run'

when it runs `status.run()`

It seems status is undefined when I run `status.run()` in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

So... Why is that and how can I make an object return itself?

Comment: cant say `return this;`, because `this` points to the `window` object

Comment: I'm running on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m on Windows 7 and it seems to be working as expected. What version of Chrome are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/KpfWh/

Comment: @Mouseroot that's not right. In a function that is a member of an object, `this` does refer to the object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method

Comment: ah wow, didn't know that,learned something new early today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set `status` like this in *Chrome* because you're really setting [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status), which **must be a *String***.

Therefore `status` becomes the *String* `"[object Object]"` (i.e. the result of casting your *Object* to *String*), and a *String* instance does not have a method called `run`, so you get an error.

Comment: And the reason the jsFiddle demos work is that the code is running inside the `onload` handler, so the `var` is local. Good find!

Comment: Right, it seems wrapping the code inside something solves the problem.